# Default GraphQL server string response when no query parameter provided?

Tags: javascript, graphql

Is it possible to hit the root `graphQL/` and return a string without specifying a query?  Just starting out creating a server, wanted to see if it was possible... doesn't seem so.  Seems like you have to at least have a query to start.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "*hit the root `graphQL/`*". Sure you could implement a `GET` route for that path which returns an arbitrary string. But to actually use GraphQL, it must be a `POST` endpoint, and the client *must* pass a query document.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want it to be graphql specs compatible then this isn't possible** ...

From specs [execution](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Execution) it must contain a document [with query/mutation]:

> A request for execution consists of a few pieces of information:
>
> - The schema to use, typically solely provided by the GraphQL service.
> - **A Document which must contain GraphQL OperationDefinition** and may contain FragmentDefinition.
> - ...

From ['Executing Requests'](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Executing-Requests) request ...

> To execute a request, the **executor must have a parsed Document and a selected operation name to run** if the document defines multiple operations, otherwise the document is expected to only contain a single operation.

... then one of possible response is an error response, e.g.

> `{"errors":[{"message":"GraphQL Request must include at least one of those two parameters: \"query\" or \"queryId\"","extensions":{"category":"request"}}],"extensions":{"debug":[]}}`

### ... if you don't care ...

**about strict graphql specs** ... and **taking assumption that probably nobody needs[/will use seriously possibly error] this response** (not tools required introspection) ... **you can return even html** (not json) 'hello, read docs' content.